# Get value from button in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, button

I've got a while loop with multiple buttons, they are like this:

```
<button onclick="confirmDelete()" value="<?php echo $game['id'];?>" name="deleteButton">Delete </button>
```

It is followed by the following confirm message:

```
<script>
function confirmDelete() {

var r = confirm(" **HERE I WANT THE ID TO START WITH** ");
if (r == true) {
    // delete
} else {
    // cancel
}
}
</script>
```

Each button has his own value, but now i want that value in my javascript when i click on that button. I tried multiple things but cant make it work.

EDIT:

If someone can tell me an better/easier way to do this, you're welcome to tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your function with `this` argument, i.e.:

```
<button onclick="confirmDelete(this)" id="myButton" value="someId" name="deleteButton">Delete </button> 
<script>
function confirmDelete(elem) {
var r = confirm(" **HERE I WANT THE ID TO START WITH** ");
var theValue = elem.value; //someId
var theId    = elem.id; //myButton
if (theValue == "True") {
    alert("True")
} else {
    alert("False")
}
}
</script>
```

---

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyZgqO

Answer (score 1):

Pass the game ID into the confirmDelete function as a parameter

```
<button onclick="confirmDelete(<?php echo $game['id'];?>)" name="deleteButton">Delete </button>

<script>
    function confirmDelete(id) {

        var r = confirm(id);
        if (r == true) {
            // delete
        } else {
            // cancel
        }
    }
</script>
```